# Set Taskbar's Background Color in the Registry

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I would like to change the W10 taskbar's background color, using Regedit.
If you know how please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Un-activated Windows 10 will eventually stop working, so customizing it may not even work, but it has no future on your machine.

Comment: Microsoft does not keep a record of "license" keys, so they are indeed telling the truth, when they indicate they don't know what your license key is.  *They only know if a license is invalid or valid*  Your Windows 7 license key is printed on the COA sticker on your device.  It's unclear what "account" you refer to to be honest.  You were never able to link Windows XP to any sort of account.  Beyond the fact you want to do something that requires your installation to be activated, it's not actually clear, what your actual question is. The solution to that problem is activate your installation

Comment: A Windows OEM license is attached to a specific machine and cannot be transferred. Your license if for the life of the machine.

Comment: Since you will likely find Windows 10 unusable without a license, either purchase a license or try another, *free*, operating system.